# how to Uncompress/Extract *.nib files from a compiled iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to get uncompressed *.nib files from a *.ipa file which is downloaded from iTunes? I know there are ways to extract the resources (jpg/png/sounds) using File juicer or similar tools. But I'm looking for a tool which can extract the *.nib or *.xib files from an *.ipa file to reuse the nib.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's impossible to do it. More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59172701/1180728

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe in an older version of Xcode, maybe 3.0 or even before, Interface Builder could read .nib files. These are basically compiled, like source code, and there is no way to decompress them or to see the contents, much like .png images are crushed.

### Update

Found a video on Youtube, http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dInaIlzVsn8, but have not tried it. Claims to be able to open compiled .nib files.

### Update 2

Here is another possible way to open a compiled .nib. This process requires you to retrieve a .nib from Hulu Desktop application, which is not compiled, and replace it's contents.

http://www.macstories.net/tutorials/how-to-edit-nib-files-in-snow-leopard/

Answer (score 6):

A bit of a late reply, but could save others the hassle of finding a better solution.

To extract the nib files from the .ipa file:

1. Rename the MyApp.ipa to MyApp.zip
2. Extract it
3. Inside the extracted folder right click the MyApp.app and press "Show package contents"
4. Here you will have all the resources, including the nib files.

To open the nib files in interface builder convert them into xib files using NibUnlocker from http://www.charlessoft.com

Comment: NibUnlocker was unable to open any of .nib files