# How to open .nib file?

Tags: swift, xcode, nib, nstouchbar

I cannot open them, XCODE just opens the application photo in XCODE and that's it. No, I cannot create a duplicate and show package contents. Any other guesses? Specifically, I'm looking to change Apple's Touch Bar functionality on PRE-EXISTING APPS. After tons of digging around to find where the TouchBar 'application' is, I've come to the conclusion that it is located in the .NIB files (new interface builder).

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064108/convert-nib-files-to-xib-files). NIB files are compiled XIB files.